# Fork in Proof-of-Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, forks

Regarding the fact that in Proof-of-Stake, a stakeholder will be elected randomly as the next author of the next block in each epoch (**or each round or slot**), logically, **in each round (or slot)** there is only a single author of block, and so a single proposed block. With these conditions, and whether this new block will be validate or not by the rest of the network, is there still the possibility of occurring a fork in each round? (As in each round a single author is selected.)

**IMPORTANT :** In this question, I mean **"slot"** by saying **"round"** and **"epoch"**.

**Related questions:**

[Proof-of-Stake: How to prevent someone from being always selected as an author of block?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/87550/23024)

[How to select the next author of block in Proof-of-Stake?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/87561/23024)

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/99074/14915

Answer (score 4):

Yes, forks are possible in Proof of Stake.

Here is an example. Assume Alice (A) is the proposer for slot 1 and Bob (B) for slot 2. The genesis (G) block is slot 0.

Alice creates the block at slot 1. This chain is G->A.

Bob never saw Alice's block so he creates the block at slot 2. This chain is G->empty->B.

There's now 2 forks. Charlie, the proposer in slot 3, can choose between either fork. (There is also a chance that Charlie could choose neither fork, and a third fork could be G->empty->empty->C.)

See [What's the difference between a Slot and a Block?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/80791/whats-the-difference-between-a-slot-and-a-block)

Comment: But I meant **in each slot**. In the question, I wrote: **in each round** that I meant  **slot**. So, Can we say that in each slot, there is no fork? Thanks

Comment: Alice could propose more than one block in slot 1. But she will likely get [slashed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83644/how-to-run-slasher-slashing-detectors-in-ethereum-2-0), which would lead to her getting ejected and banned from being a validator. A technical paper you may be interested in about the topic: https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.03052

Comment: @Questioner No, since there's a fork in slot 1 in this example -- does it contain block A or is it empty? Unless the plan is to wait forever for a block, there can always be disagreement over whether a block was placed in that slot or whether the timeout expired. That is a fork as someone who thinks a block was placed in that slot might rely on a transaction in that block being accepted.